# Are Refunds For Android In App Consumable Purchases Supported? - In App Billing API V3

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm not specifically looking to have the option to refund a user for an in app purchase of a consumable, but just in the odd case that a user asks for a refund, either through google, or through the developer of an in app purchase of a consumable.

There does not seem any way of handling refunds through the In App Billing api V3. All documentation points to V2 of the api using broadcast receivers. This does not help me in least bit.

So how are refunds handled in the In App Billing v3 api? I'm assuming for a non consumable, the refund is processed, and then google handles the processing through their backend, and then when a getPurchaseState() is conducted, it would return a value of 2 (refunded). If so, this works great for a NON CONSUMABLE product.

When a getPurchaseState() call to a consumable purchase is made, it returns null. That's assuming if the purchase was previously successful, and that the item was consumed and provisioned. I figure I could store the purchase items locally within the app, but then there is still no way of receiving a refund notification for that product. I can check for purchase state, but again, it will return null, as long as it was consumed and provisioned already.

A slight workaround I can think of right now, is to not consume the purchase on provisioning. So that it remains "unconsumed" according to google, and remains in their database. Now, if a refund is requested, I am assuming a call to getPurchaseState() for that consumable will return refunded, thus the application logic can then subtract/deduct the provisioned consumable from user's inventory. If a user would want to repurchase that consumable again, then before the IAB api call is made for the purchase, get the purchaseState() and/or hasPurchase(), and if there is already a purchase there, consume that item without provisioning, this will let the user repurchase that consumable. Only issue with this workaround, is that if A user wants to re purchase the same consumable product, as soon as the select the option to repurchase, the item must be consumed regardless of whether they successfully repurchase the product or not. So if the user does not complete the purchase, the product is already consumed, and I end up back where I am now with inability to check for refund state on the consumable.

I can't think of any other way to do a refund for a consumable in app product, and that is what I ask here. Is the way I thought of sufficient, or is there a proper way to handle refunds using IAP v3 on consumables?
I was thinking I have 3 options:

1. Don't offer refunds for consumables, no/little exceptions, but the issue with this is if a user requests refund through google, and not through developer, leading to option 3 below)
2. Find a workaround (either properly through the api, or with my proposed workaround)
3. Offer refunds, but have no application logic to subtract/deduct the consumable. In this scenario, users could end up taking advantage of free purchases.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a super late response to this issue, but it took me quite some time to track down info on this issue, so hopefully it can help someone else out. There are a few ways of doing this... In the Google Play Developer console you can click on the left nav saying "Order Management" which will bring up a list of all recent orders though your app. If you need to refund one you can click on it, or multi select them and refund them in this view. Just a heads up... you will most likely need permissions from your account admin to see this view and refund users.

Your other option is though the API [docs here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/orders/refund). You will need to set up your API account though the Android console, which I will say is a massive pain and not clear. But once that's set up and your "Server Applications" is set up you will need to make sure it has proper permissions as well. Then you should be able to use a library such as [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) to do the heavy lifting for you, because from what I've read the JWT auth process though the google API is not super straightforward, and their docs are a mess. I hope this helps someone and comment if you have questions... I will do my best to answer.

This same API also can be used to find items that were purchased by users and then refunded, so you can remove these items from those users' apps. Also you can do server side purchase validation through this as well, which is highly recommended, because rooted phones can inject fake purchase requests making your app believe that it's hearing back from the google play store, but in reality it's not. You then send back to your server the purchase token and SKU of the item being purchased and then on your server you just run [this](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get). This will give you back a 400 error if it's invalid, and a 200 with a some JSON data if it's a successful purchase.